# Polymer - Creating a list of custom elements within a custom element

Tags: json, templates, repeat, polymer

I am trying to get my head around Polymer. Right now I have successfully created a custom news element (my-newsbite) and can populate and display attribute data from the page calling the custom element.

The next step is to create a second custom element (my-newsbite-list), that takes multiple news items in the form of a json object from attributes in the calling page and displays a list of the my-newsbite custom elements.

For some reason I am unable to get it to work.

My test index.php page calls the my-newsbite-list like this...

```
<div style="width:200px;">
    <my-newsbite-list news="[{title: 'title here',date:'12 July 2014',content:'content here',url:'http://www.frfrf.com'}]">
    </my-newsbite-list>
</div>
```

The my-newsbite-list custom element looks like this...

```
<link rel="import" href="../components/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="my-newsbite-list" attributes="news" >

<template >

    <template repeat="{{item in news}}">

        <my-newsbite title="item.title" date="item.date" content="item.content" url="item.url">
        </my-newsbite>

    </template>

</template>

  <script>
    Polymer('my-newsbite-list', {
        created: function() {           
            this.news = []; // Initialize and hint type to an object.           
        }       
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

And finally my custom element my-newsbite looks like this...

```
<link rel="import" href="../components/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">


<polymer-element name="my-newsbite" attributes="title date content url width">

  <template>

    <div class="my-newsbite-title">
    {{title}}
    <div class="my-newsbite-date">{{date}}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="my-newsbite-content">{{content}}...</div>
    <div class="my-newsbite-url"><a href="{{url}}">more...</a></div>  

    <style>
      :host {
        /* Note: by default elements are always display:inline. */
        display: block;
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        font-fam 
      }
      .my-newsbite-title {
        /* Note: by default elements are always display:inline. */
        display: block;
        background-color:#06F;
        color:white;
        padding:3px;
      }
      .my-newsbite-content{
          padding:3px;
      }
      .my-newsbite-date{
          padding:3px;
          font-size:8pt;
          text-align:right;
          float:right;
      }
      .my-newsbite-url{
          padding:3px;
      }



     </style>

  </template>

  <script>
   Polymer('my-newsbite', {
     title: "****",
     date: "****",
     content: "****...",
     url: "http://****.com",    
    });
  </script>

</polymer-element>
```

The end result of all this is a blank rendered index page.

Can anyone see why the json object is not rendered with in the my-newsbite-list custom element ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing I see wrong is you're not adding in the template tags correctly here: `<my-newsbite title="item.title"` ... Shouldn't it be: `<my-newsbite title="{{item.title}}"`

Comment: Thanks badsyntax, you're right about the need for the {{}}. Sometimes I miss the obvious things, however, that hasn't solved the problem. I'm still getting a blank rendered page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had already tried ebidel's suggestion but that didn't solve it.

Scott Miles is correct...

Polymer is very fussy about the JSON format passed in the attribute. (I don't know how to give you credit for the answer from a comment.)

So, in the index.php page the code looks like this (Note the double quotes around both the key names and the values)...

```
<my-newsbite-list news='[{"title":"sdfg","date":"12 July 2014","content":"sdfg sdfg sdfg sdfg sdfg sdfg sdf","url":"http://www.frfrf.com"}]'>
</my-newsbite-list>
```

The custom element Polymer javascript looks like this...

```
Polymer('my-newsbite-list', {   
news: [],   
    ready: function(){          
    }
});
```

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Thank you Craig your question and answers were really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to lie in the way the json object in the calling attribute is received by the custom element. Adding the following code to the Polymer ready function fixes the issue.

```
Polymer('my-newsbite-list', {       
    ready: function(){
        this.news = eval(this.news) || [];
    }
});
```

This solution does work, but the correct method is shown in the answer above.

Comment: You shouldn't need `eval()`. if you just hint the type in `ready: function() {this.news = []; }`, does it work?

Comment: Stringified objects must be valid JSON to be parsed. All keys must be quoted, and you may only use double-quotes.
`[{"title": "title here", "date":"12 July 2014","content":"content here","url":"http://www.frfrf.com"}]`. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks ebidel, tried that already. Scott Miles comment is correct and answer is updated.